# It is necessary to find the file on all partitions

Tags: ansible

There are a large number of servers with different connected partitions.
It is necessary to find 1 specific file on all partitions.

I am performing a file search

```yaml
  - name: search .file
      stat:
        path: " ???????/.file"
      register: stat_result

    - name: print server name
      debug:
        msg: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
      when: stat_result.stat.exists
```

How do I find all the disks on the servers and substitute them in the search?

Need a list of servers where file found.

Answer (score 0):

> *How do I find all the disks on the servers and substitute them in the search?*

Since you like to search within all partitions and do not like to specify anything further here, it might be a better job for the [`find` module – Return a list of files based on specific criteria](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html).

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - find:
      paths: /
      recurse: yes
      file_type: file
      pattern: ".file"
      use_regex: true
      hidden: "true"
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.files }}"
    when: result.matched != 0
```

will result for server and if the file was found into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - atime: 1676487500.000000
    ctime: 1676487500.000000
    dev: 1000
    gid: 1000
    gr_name: ansible_users
    inode: 1234567
    isblk: false
    ischr: false
    isdir: false
    isfifo: false
    isgid: false
    islnk: false
    isreg: true
    issock: false
    isuid: false
    mode: '0644'
    mtime: 1676487500.000000
    nlink: 1
    path: /home/user/test/.file
...
```

will start a search recursive from the given root `\` and if correct access rights are given on all mounted partitions, directories, etc.

**Please Note**

Since that might cause a significant amount of I/O operations (IOps), maybe even over the wire (network), it is strongly recommended to decrease the search path and pattern as much as possible. The same is recommended because of the access right as it might trigger an unwanted amount of `access denied` messages.